# Erro ao acessar método em uma classe

Tags: android

Dentro de *src* tenho um pacote chamado *meus_utils* e neste pacote tenho a classe *utillog*.
Nesta classe tenho o método

```
public static boolean gerouLog(Context context){
    return true;
}
```

Quando vou acessar este método pela classe MainActivity, dá o seguinte erro:

**the source attachment does not contain the source for the file classloader.class android**

Código que está acessando o método na classe MainActivity:

```
import meus_utils.UtilLog;

public static boolean retornaGerouLog()
{
    boolean b = utillogs.gerouLog(this);

    return b;
}
```

---

[image: o meu Properties]

o meu activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

e o *java -version* e *javac -version* estão com os mesmos valores

Comment: Poderia incluir a hierarquia a partir da pasta src?

Comment: myLocal -> com.example.mylocal -> MainActivity.java ----------     myLocal -> meus_utils -> utillog.java -> gerouLog()

Comment: Por qual motivo você passa em `utillogs.gerouLog(this);` uma activity como parâmetro?

Comment: no método gerouLog eu uso o context.clearWallpaper();

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente verifique se a sua Activity está sendo configurada de forma correta no AndroidManifest.xml.
ex:

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.task.secondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Caso não funcione, verifique se as suas versões do JDK e do JRE se são compatíveis com os comandos:

```
javac -version

java - version
```

Caso não funcione, tente ver o seu Build Path se está apontando para o local correto do seu JDK nas configurações do próprio eclipse no caminho:  Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries.

Se nada disso pegar, tente fazer um teste instanciando o MainActivity em outra classe criando ela como um intent com o código:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondactivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

ps: Não esqueça de registrar no AndroidManifest.xml

E caso nenhuma das opções funcionar, posta aqui o que está saindo no Logcat para analisarmos melhor!

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

Comment: Posta o erro exatamente como está saindo no Logcat

Comment: não sae no LogCat ele abre uma aba com o título ClassLoader.class, nela contém um botão que abre o explorer *Change Attached Source* e abaixo o seguinte código:
`// Compiled from ClassLoader.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public abstract class java.lang.ClassLoader {
  
  // Method descriptor #8 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  protected ClassLoader();
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]...`

Comment: Pode ser que as duas classes ".class" foram compiladas na versão do java 1.5 e seu projeto está rodando com uma versão inferior...baixe o java 6, e modifique o caminho (PATH em variáveis de ambiente) do seu java pra apontar pro 1.6 e teste.

Verifique também no eclipse se ele ta apontando para a pasta certa do java 1.6 em:

window ---> preferences ---> java ---> installed jre's ---> clique add e selecione lá.

Comment: fiz um teste com a classe ConnectivityManager dentro da classe MainActivity e qnd vai instanciar o método dá o mesmo erro !!

Comment: Faça o que eu disse acima, atualize as versões do java e modifique no PATH do sistema e no Android também.

Comment: Conseguiu cara?

Comment: Não resolveu, fiz a atualização do java e nada. Baixei a versão do Android Studio, mas para fazer as atualizações do SDK Manager está muito lento. :(

Comment: Complicado...tente trocar a IDE de desenvolvimento e teste, caso funcionar, adeus ao Eclipse. :P